# multiprocessing: how to send data from parent to continuously running child process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

Is it possible to use multiprocessing to send data to a running child process? For example, running a web server in a child process and using the parent process to send data to the server. I found [this question about the exact reverse of my situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036577/python-multiprocessing-child-process-constantly-sending-back-results-and-keeps) (i.e. continuous updates from a running child process back to the parent). Is there a way to get this to work? My understanding is that multiprocessing.Queue only sends/receives data on process termination. This pseudocode gives a skeleton of what I'd like to do:

```
def server(q):
    //start eventlet server
    q.get() // --> does something

q = Queue()
p = Process(target=server, args=(q,))
p.start()
q.put("some kind of command")
```

Comment: Hello rustbird, can you give a little more details as to the context of what you are trying to do exactly. If you have a web server as a child process why not just communicate with it  over http. Have you considered using a Task Queue like celery ? https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you misread the answer you quoted. The `multiprocessing.Queue` was designed for exactly the purpose you describe. Maybe check out the reference documentation for that class? An alternative may also be `multiprocessing.Pipe`.

Comment: In my code, the q.get() command is never reached because the eventlet server is still running. I can't figure out how to keep the server running & pass data to it with queues.

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudocode runs almost exactly as written:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import time

def server(q):
    while True:
        stuff = q.get()
        print(stuff, flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=server, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    for i in range(5):
        q.put(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

This script creates a parent process that executes a long-running task and a child process that does work in the background. When the parent process is finished, it sends a message to the child to stop, the child receives the message, it stops what it's doing, sends a message back to the parent that it's stopped, the parent receives the message, and then stops itself.

```py
import queue, time
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.send_signal_queue = Queue()
        self.receive_signal_queue = Queue()

        self.startChild()

        print('Begin long-running task in parent.')
        time.sleep(10)
        print('End long-running task in parent.')

        self.stopChild()

    def startChild(self):
        self.Child = Child(self.send_signal_queue, self.receive_signal_queue)
        self.Child.start()

    def stopChild(self):
        self.send_signal_queue.put('Stop')

        while True:
            try:
                self.receive_signal_queue.get_nowait()
                break
            except queue.Empty:
                time.sleep(1)

        self.Child.terminate()
        self.Child.join()

class Child(Process):
    def __init__(self, receive_signal_queue, send_signal_queue):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.receive_signal_queue = receive_signal_queue
        self.send_signal_queue = send_signal_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.receive_signal_queue.get_nowait()
                break
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

            print('Child doing work while parent is busy.')
            time.sleep(1)

        self.send_signal_queue.put('Stopped')

Parent()
```